# Porter Stemmer in While loop having problem

Tags: php

this is my query

```
 $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM questions WHERE MATCH (question) AGAINST ('$msg*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ");
```

while loop

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $i = $row ["id"]; 
            $q = $row ["question"];   
             $a = $row ["answer"];
            $str1 = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $q));
            $word_count_1 = explode(" ", cleanWords($str1));
            print_r($word_count_1);

            foreach($word_count_1 as $word) 
             {
            $stem = PorterStemmer::Stem($word);
            if(!in_array($stem, $stop_words)) {
            $stem_words[] = $stem;
            }
            }
     $Databasemsg =implode(" ",$stem_words);
     echo "<br>";     
     $msg2 =strtolower($Databasemsg);
     echo "<br>";         
     print_r($msg2);
      similar_text($msg2,$msg, $percent1);  
}
```

$msg varaible is stemmed input of the user;

However my comparing in similar_text method is getting lower and lower because this is the result when i print $msg2

The  results keeps incrementing like this one

```
what is life
what is life what is life Usa
what is life what is life Usa what is life in canda
what is life what is life Usa what is life in canda what is life in germany
```

I want to get is

```
what is life 
what is life Usa 
what is life in canda 
what is life in germany
```

to compare it properly using similar text method

Comment: put print_r($msg2) outside of the while(). Leave the rest so it continues to loop but only present the end result.

Comment: if i do that the result will be only one how can i compare the remaining results?

Comment: perhaps resetting $msg after each iteration? $msg = "";

Comment: Same results bro just one result

Comment: sorry, put the print_r back inside the loop :)

Comment: alternatively and probably more cumbersome than resetting $msg each time, you could str_replace each iteration.

Comment: Can you please not use the `>` character for text? That's for errors/quoting. I took the time to remove them earlier and you added them back in; why?

Comment: Sorry sir, I think i need another foreach loop for every array but how dont know how to make a counter for each results.

Comment: I'll give it more attention when I get home. We'll get this sorted :)

Comment: Thanks man. if i compare the iterated $msg2 using similarity text perctage got lower because it is compared to (what is life==what is life what is life in Usa)

Comment: Maybe we're over thinking this. Try this:  
```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $i = $row ["id"]; 
            $q = $row ["question"];   
            $a = $row ["answer"];
            $p = similar_text(strtolower($q), strtolower($msg))  / strlen($msg) * 100;
     if ($p == 100) {
                print_r(question);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Not quite sure how to format this code in comments. Sorry. 
This version makes sure that all of the words in the $msg are in the question. Changing the 100 in "if ($p == 100)" to 90 will match 90% of the letters.

Comment: Yup i have that restriction, the problem is when i use the method porter stemmer the array size keeps incrementing and incrementing

Comment: Makes the comparing percentage lesser and lesser depends on how many row lines result

Comment: What is life  , similartext (what is life, what is life) the result is 100 percent but

Comment: But if its increment the array gets the recenet

Comment: The comparing was just like this

Comment: Similartext (what is life, what is life what is life in uk) lessen the similarity

Comment: If is possible to subtract redudant in array?